# Finding angular velocity and velocity from angle and distance

Tags: math, model, coordinates, trigonometry, state-space

I have coordinater turn model (CT) and I need to be able to find the angular velocity (w) and velocity (v) from recorded data. However I can't seem to figure out how to derive the velocity from the data. The problem formulation is as follows:

[image]

As you can see I know the angular difference, coordinate difference and the time between the states. I know a way to get the angular velocity but i can not figure out how to derive v. Anyone knows the correct formula given the assumptions I've made?

Regards, Jakob

Comment: Assuming that the trajectory is a circular arc (constant linear speed and angular velocity), the angle that it subtends is equal to `θ2-θ1`. Use this angle and `d` (chord length) to calculate the radius of this circle, and multiply by the angular velocity `w` to obtain `v`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to math.stackexchange.com